# Prove that group $\mathbb{Q}\times Z_2$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

I need some help with the following question.

> Prove that group $\mathbb{Q}\times Z_2$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}.$

*My proof:*

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ and let $\phi$ be isomorphism.We have $\phi(a,x)\phi((b,x)=\phi((a,x)(b,x))=\phi(ab,1)=\phi(a,1)\phi(b,1)$
But $\phi(a,x)\phi((b,x)\neq \phi(a,1)\phi(b,1).$ Thus $\phi$ isn't  isomorphism.

**Is  proof true?**

Comment: I have no idea what your argument is supposed to be, but perhaps a place to start is to see that one of these groups has a non-identity element of finite order and the other does not.

Comment: You should mention the operations of the group. A group is always a tuple $(G,\circ)$ consisting a set and an operation.

Comment: @ PVAL Did you mean $(1,x)^2=(1,1)?$

Comment: Your argument is just writing down the definition of a homomorphism and then asserting that $\phi(a, x)\phi(b, x) \not= \phi(a, 1)\phi(b, 1)$ without any justification. That's not a valid proof.

Comment: @anomaly The followinng proof is true? Group $\mathbb{Q}\times Z_2$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ because $(1,x) \in \mathbb{Q}\times Z_2 $ is element of order $2$ but $\mathbb{Q}$ has not  a non-identity element of finite order.

Comment: @Liza Yes, this last proof is correct, and it's the shortest one could think about.

Comment: @Crostul Thanks for the help :)

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is *not* a group under multiplication ($0 \in \Bbb Q$ has no multiplicative inverse), so $(1,x)$ is *not* of finite order in $\Bbb Q \times \Bbb Z_2$. The element you seek is $(0,1)$, assuming the group operation in each factor is addition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that the operation of your group is component-wise multiplication. This is not possible, as $\Bbb Q \times \Bbb Z_2$ is not a group under that operation, as $(0,0)$ has no multiplicative inverse.

Instead, the proper operation should be component-wise addition, with the addition of the second coordinate modulo $2$.

Note that if we had such an isomorphism, $\phi$, its kernel is necessarily $\{(0,0)\}$. However:

$\phi((0,1)) + \phi((0,1)) = \phi((0,1) + (0,1)) = \phi((0,0)) = 0$. If we set:

$\phi((0,1)) = q$, the above tells us that $q + q = 0 \implies q = 0$ (since $q$ is rational).

Hence, $(0,1) \in \text{ker }\phi$, contradicting our assumption that $\phi$ is an isomorphism (since all isomorphisms are injective).

Answer (score 2):

The group Q*Z2 has an element (0,1), which is of order two, but Q doesn't have an element of order two. That's why we can't define any isomorphism between them.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see that $\mathbf Q$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbf Q\times Z_2$ is to use the fact that $\mathbf Q$ is divisible while $\mathbf Q\times Z_2$ is not.

**Definition.** A group $G$ is *divisible* if for each $x\in G$ and each nonzero integer $k$, there is some $y\in G$ such that
$$
x = y^k \quad\text{or, written additively,}\quad x = ky.
$$
Intuitively, divisibility of a group is equivalent to the existence of integer roots of elements of the group.

**Proposition.** $\mathbf Q$ is divisible. (Check this.)

Put $G=\mathbf Q\times Z_2$. Negating the definition of divisibility, we want to show that there is some $x\in G$ and some nonzero integer $k$ such that for all $y\in G$, $x \ne ky$. Put $x = (2,1)$ and $k = 2$. For the sake of contradiction, suppose that $(q,z)\in G$ satisfies $(2,1)=2(q,z)$. Then,
$$
2(q,z)=(q,z)+(q,z)=(2q,2z).
$$
Evidently $q=1$ if there is any hope for this to work out. However, $2z\equiv 0\pmod 2$, for all $z\in Z_2$. Hence, the second coordinate can never be $1$, no matter which $z$ we pick in $Z_2$, so $G$ is not divisible. Since divisibility is preserved under isomorphisms, the claim is proved.